# I have a defined variable but the code says it is not defined

Tags: python, variables, undefined, frames

I am trying to add the option to tell the player if they have won or loss in the frame.

[image]

Comment: Post your **code**, not an image of your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at [MCVE] , a helpful page that describes how to post a problem such that others can easily execute it, see what you are trying to do and see where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: It is very difficult to see what's going on from the image you posted, but if I had to guess, I'd say that `guess` is defined inside another function.  It is then referenced outside of that function, when it isn't visible, which results in the undefined reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `guess()` is declared inside another function, thus the main scope doesn't recognize it.
you must implement your functions in the main scope.